# add service in __construct of controller

Tags: symfony, service, constructor

i would like in __construct controller,use a service.
so, i followed the cookbook : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

but i don't work, this is my code :

```
 class CheckoutController extends Controller
 {
private $checkoutService;

public function __construct(Panier $checkoutService){
    $this->session = new Session();


    if (!$this->session->has('panier')){
        $this->checkoutService = $checkoutService;
        $this->session->set('panier',$this->checkoutService);
    }
    if (!$this->session->has('etape')) $this->session->set('etape',0);

}`
```

i declared this controller in my service.xml :

`acme.checkout_controller:
        class: acme\EcommerceBundle\Controller\CheckoutController
        arguments: [@kiyoi.getCheckout]`

so i get this error,

`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to acme\EcommerceBundle\Controller\CheckoutController::__construct() must be an instance of acme\EcommerceBundle\Checkout\Panier, none given, called in /var/www/v2-acme-site/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2176 and defined`

i don't understand why i get this error!!

you know another solution to use a service in the constructor of the controller?thanks for your help

Comment: And be aware that what you are doing with the session makes no sense and is not going to work the way you think it will.

Comment: why this is the bad method?

Comment: Well, you create a new session and then check to see if there is anything in it?  And then you try to store a service into a session?  Might want to go back to the basics here.

Comment: i check if in the session,there is the key 'panier'!!!it's different!!this->session is an object of symfony!!!and why i can't store a service into session???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to change your routing to use the service name to make this work.

from this

`checkout :
    path:     /checkout
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Cart:checkout}`

to this

`checkout:
    path:     /checkout
    defaults: { _controller: acme.checkout_controller:checkout}`

Comment: thanks for your help.i I had forgotten to alter routes.but i must replace checkout by checkoutAction in the route.

Comment: when using controller as Service you can omit Action prefix in both routing and controller